# EtherEx decentralized exchange

Tags: dapps, exchanges, decentralization, etherex

Been waiting for a long time to be able to access a decentralized exchange. When will EtherEx be launched and will it support BTC ETH pair?

Answer (score 3):

On the [etherex subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherEx/comments/3wzmkc/is_this_project_still_alive/) someone asked if the project was still alive. The [answer given](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherEx/comments/3wzmkc/is_this_project_still_alive/cy0kngs) was

> Yes it is, it's just been quiet lately. The Token Standard is being
>   finalized, something that was crucially needed for this project to
>   move forward. Integration with btcrelay is ongoing with an already
>   working implementation on the testnet. There are constant updates to
>   the UI, with most of the upcoming work focusing on improving the
>   general UX and trading experience.
>
> We're currently organizing the security audit, the most important step
>   before going live.

The [FAQ](https://etherex.org/faq) has the question:

**How will cryptocoins that are not on the ethereum blockchain (BTC, LTC, etc) work on EtherEx?**

The first version of Ethereum will not be able to store off chain cryptocoins in contracts. Therefore, we are tasked in the short term with finding a way to incorporate these into our trading engine while also sticking to our core principals of openness and decentralization. We are exploring many options and think a combination of resources currently available to the public (such as multisig wallets) will give us the ability to make this happen efficiently. Once a future version of Ethereum fully supports off chain cryptos, this will be a much easier task.